# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

Tags: c++, string, exception

```
string Solution::findDigitsInBinary(int A) {
    int i, j, rem;

    if(A == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        string res="";

        while(A > 0) {
            rem = A % 2;
            res = res + to_string(rem);
            A = A / 2;
        }

        return std::string(res.rbegin(), res.rend());
    }
}
```

how to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

The problem caused by:

```
if(A == 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

When `A == 0` it tries to [construct an `std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) from `0`. This is equal – because the implicit constructor call – to:

```
return std::string(0);
```

In this case the `0` means a **null pointer** which is illegal. The error message

> basic_string::_M_construct **null not valid**

means exactly the same.

If you wish to return zero when `A == 0`, you can solve it by changing the `return 0` to:

```
return "0";
```

Comment: I'm curious about the downvote. Is the downvoter found a serious problem in my answer what couldn't suggest to edit in comments?

Answer (score 0):

`return 0;` calls implicit string constructor accepting a pointer to char `return std::string(const char *(0))`. This pointer is not allowed to be null. To return an empty string write `return std::string()`;

Answer (score 0):

Since the method is expected to return a `std::string` so you are returning a `std::string(0)` ~ `std::string(NULL)` if `A == 0` is `true`.

To return a default value for `std::string` - I guess - simply `return std::string();` instead of `return 0;`.